# Hi, I am trying to identify why this contact form won't send. Is already on the server and after I press Send message nothing comes through

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, contacts

The contact details are not sending. I will appreciate if anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong. The website is already live and I have used the correct email address in PHP. Not sure 100 if there is any info that will go into head of the HTML contact form.

Thanks

HTML Code:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <br>
      <h2 class="contact-title">Get in Touch</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <form class="form-contact contact_form" action="contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm"
        novalidate="novalidate">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">

              <textarea class="form-control w-100" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="9"
                onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Message'"
                placeholder='Enter Message'></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'" placeholder='Enter your name'>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'" placeholder='Enter email address'>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" type="text" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
                onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'" placeholder='Enter Subject'>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mt-3">
          <a href="#" class="btn_3 button-contactForm" >Send Message</a>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

PHP Code:

```
    <?php

    $to = "i have used a correct email address";
    $from = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
    $cmessage = $_REQUEST['message'];

    $headers = "From: $from";
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $subject = "You have a message from your Bitmap Photography.";

    $logo = 'img/logo.png';
    $link = '#';

    $body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Express Mail</title> 
        </head><body>";
    $body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
    $body .= "<thead style='text-align: center;'><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>";
    $body .= "<a href='{$link}'><img src='{$logo}' alt=''></a><br><br>";
    $body .= "</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Name:</strong> {$name}</td>";
    $body .= "<td style='border:none;'><strong>Email:</strong> {$from}</td>";
    $body .= "</tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'><strong>Subject:</strong> {$csubject}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td></td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td colspan='2' style='border:none;'>{$cmessage}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "</tbody></table>";
    $body .= "</body></html>";

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

?>
```

The contact details are not sending. I will appreciate if anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong. The website is already live and I have used the correct email address in PHP. Not sure 100 if there is any info that will go into head of the html contact form.

Comment: Instead of a link <a href="#" class="btn_3 button-contactForm" >Send Message</a>
change to a button type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a couple of changes in your code to make the mail work. First you Have to change the code for the button. It must be like: `<button type="submit"class="btn_3 button-contactForm">Send Message</button>`  you also have to change the code in the PHP file for sending the mail you have to remove the $send and make it just like `mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);`  You also have to note that not all hosting companies support the mail() PHP function. So make sure your web hosting provider supports the mail() function. If your hosting service does not support the PHP mail() function, you have to use the PHPMailer class. PHPMailer uses SMTP and sends the mail with the form data. You can download the PHPMailer class with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/). There are also other websites you can download that from. After you unzip the downloaded zip file, you would notice there is a folder named PHPMailer which has a lot of other PHP files inside it. You don't have to change any other PHP files. Make sure an `autoload.php` file is present in the folder, because the autoload.php file is the file which gets and combines all the necessary classes for the SMTP mail. After that, you have to upload the PHPMailer folder to your root directory in your server (with FTP for shared hosting or just copy paste for dedicated servers). First You have to create a gmail or any mail account through which the PHPMailer sends the mail. After creating an account, go to settings of the account and make sure 2 step authentication is disabled. After that also turn on Less Secure app, which you can do [from here](https://myaccount.google.com/intro/security).
After doing all that, you have to create two PHP files which sends the form data, the first one will be contact_process.php as you mentioned above and the code for the php file will be:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'phpmail/vendor/autoload.php';
if($_POST)
{
require('constant.php');
    
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject     = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $msg   = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


   $mail = new PHPMailer(true);  
    //   $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                               
       $mail->isSMTP();
       $mail->SMTPAuth = true;    
       $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
       $mail->Port = 465;          
      $mail -> Host = HOST;  //this gets called from the constant.php
       $mail->Username = USERNAME;               
       $mail->Password = PASSWORD; 
       $mail->From = $user_email;
       $mail->FromName = $user_name;
       $mail->addAddress(RECIPIENT_MAIL,RECIPIENT_MAIL_NAME); //this gets called from the constant.php do not change this
       $mail->isHTML(true);
       $mail->Subject = $subject;
       $mail->Body = "New Response from website :\n\n<br>".    
                     "Name: $user_name\n\n<br>".       
                     "Email: $user_email \n\n<br>".    
                     "Subject: $subject \n\n<br>".       
                     "Message: \n\n <br>".    "$msg\n\n<br>"; 
        $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Try Again later')); //error sending form
             exit;
        } else {
            //mail sent successfully
            header("Location: thankyou.php");//change the link to the thank you page
                                     exit;
        }
}
?>
```

Now a constant.php file must be created where the reciepient and sender must be configured. The code for that will be:

```
<?php
// SMTP Configuration
define('HOST',"ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
define('USERNAME',"sending-mail@gmail.com"); //mail address of gmail you created
define('PASSWORD',"password-of-sending-mail-acc"); //password of gmail you created

// Recipient Configuration
define('RECIPIENT_MAIL',"recipient@gmail.com"); //enter mail address you want the form data to get received
define('RECIPIENT_MAIL_NAME',"Website"); //name of recipient
?>
```

Make sure all the files are in the root directory. You can also add the files to other directories but have to change the directory linking for the files.

For more Detailed documentation and source code you can [see this.](https://github.com/BraxtonElmer/PHPMailer-Send-Form-Data-To-Email/blob/master/README.md)